# D.C Fontana, famed Star Trek writer, passed away on December 2nd

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Star Trek wouldn't be Star Trek without her. She wrote many of the best episodes, helped develop the universe and gave us that series that we have loved for decades now.

More information on [Startrek.com](https://intl.startrek.com/news/dc-fontana-1939-2019)

*Salutes*

Comment: What a badass name. Sounds like she should be in a western. #RIP

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - her name was Dorothy, but she wrote as "D.C" to keep from getting scripts rejected from her earliest gigs: westerns. "I was being turned down for interviews. They were saying 'I don't think a woman can write this show. I'd say 'but I've got six credits on westerns. Why don't you think I can write this?' The answer was always the same: writers for television came with first names like Gene, Sam, and Rod - not Dorothy. And so the pen name of D.C. Fontana was born" - 'These Are the Voyages: Season 1" - Marc Cushman

Comment: On a tangentially related note, Robert Walker, jr. who was the guest star in the  classic TOS episode "Charlie X" (that Fontana wrote) passed away on Dec. 5th.